# Using Eclipse Uml Generator 0.9

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, uml

I would like to use Eclipse Uml Generator 0.9 to reverse engineer my java code to many different uml diagrams, such as package, class, and sequence. There is zero documentation on how this can be done. Does anyone know how to use this plugin?

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but you could also reverse java into UML by using Papyrus Designer (https://wiki.eclipse.org/Papyrus_Software_Designer)

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with your statement about the docs for this being undercover.

Nevertheless, [Cedric Notot](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/user/cnotot/listings) which is the maintainer of the plugin, writes this comment on the [eclipse site](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-uml-generators) regarding the release docs:

> "Note that the current released version of UML Generators is 0.9.0 and be aware that it is in incubation.
>   To know how to launch a generation, you can read the related release note here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_UML_Generators/New_and_Noteworthy/0.9.0.
>   **You can read more documentation in the Help > Help Contents > UML Generators Documentation menu of your Eclipse IDE**.
>   At last, an 1.0.0 release is going to be built very soon. If you have some remarks, do not hesitate to create a bugzilla ticket. Thanks."
>
> *Submitted by Cedric Notot on Mon, 2015-10-19 09:54*

I have not checked the value of the above comment myself, but I'm sure that's a good place to start looking.

Good luck!